# AngularJS: ng-switch not working

Tags: angularjs

I have been looking around for a way to display an HTML content block based on a selection.

I prefer not to use `ng-include` for this one. I looked at `ng-if` and `ng-show/hide`.

I would like to do this with `ng-switch`, on [this demo](http://docs-angularjs-org-dev.appspot.com/api/ng.directive%3angSwitch) it seems to work... But not in my code, any suggestions?

**HTML:**

```
<select ng-change="selectedAction(selectedType)" 
        ng-model="selectedType" 
        ng-options="type.name for type in relationshipType">

    <option value="">-- Select item --</option>

</select>

<div ng-switch on="selectedType">
    <span ng-switch-when="king">
       King Julien
    </span>
    <span ng-switch-when="Feet">
       Mort
    </span>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.relationshipType = [{name:'king'},{name:'feet'}];
```

Comment: Can you post Fiddle/Plunker?

Comment: @MaximShoustin I have problems creating fiddles for angular examples... It just never seem to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You write `type.name for type in relationshipType`. This will select the entire object, e.g. `{name:'feet'}` which is different than the string `feet`. Try:

```
<div ng-switch on="selectedType.name">
    <span ng-switch-when="king">
    ...
```

Also, comparison is case sensitive, so:

```
<span ng-switch-when="feet">
```

(lower-case f, as defined in model)

Comment: yes they have a name property, sorry about that. But that shouldn't matter because I am passing the selected on the `ng-model="selectedType"` and that is made availabe `<div ng-switch on="selectedType">`